# TCL Json object with dash

Tags: json, parsing, tcl

using tcl, a can create and parse json object 
but if the element name  contain a dash (-), the created string is no more  seen as a valid Json object

```
set jsonStr {{
    "Image": {
        "Width":  800,
        "Height": 600,
        "Title":  "View from 15th Floor",
        "Thumbnail": {
            "Url":    "http://www.example.com/image/481989943",
            "Height": 125,
            "Width":  100
        },
        "Animated" : false,
        "IDs": [116, 943, 234, 38793],      
        "valid-access" : [

        ]
    }
} }
set valid_obj [::json:object? $jsonStr ]
puts "is object $valid_obj \n"
```

In this case, valid_obj is equal to '0'. when i puts "validaccess" instead of "valid-access", it work fine and i can parse the json object without any problem.

what i have missed ? is there any specific treatment that i have to do to accept the 'dash' character in the element name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know where the command `::json:object?` came from (perhaps [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40865)?), but it does not appear to be part of the `json` package in Tcllib. **It's also wrong;** your JSON object is correct.

By contrast, if I use the package from Tcllib:

```
package require Tcl 8.6
package require json 1.2
set jsonStr {{
    "Image": {
        "Width":  800,
        "Height": 600,
        "Title":  "View from 15th Floor",
        "Thumbnail": {
            "Url":    "http://www.example.com/image/481989943",
            "Height": 125,
            "Width":  100
        },
        "Animated" : false,
        "IDs": [116, 943, 234, 38793],      
        "valid-access" : [

        ]
    }
} }
puts [json::json2dict $jsonStr]
```

Then I get this output:

```
Image {Width 800 Height 600 Title {View from 15th Floor} Thumbnail {Url http://www.example.com/image/481989943 Height 125 Width 100} Animated false IDs {116 943 234 38793} valid-access {}}
```

which looks exactly correct to me.

---

Actually, looking at that Wiki page indicates that that's indeed where you got the code from. The example is recognisably similar. Fixing that code for you is going to be a matter of changing `[string is wordchar $k]` in the definition of `object?` to `[regexp {^[-\w]+$} $k]`. Though it is still a bit dodgy; JSON keys can legally contain (almost) *any* character. The real restrictions are because of the way that `json::select` on that same page works.

It's example code, not production-grade.